# Validation on dynamic table using javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function checkmatch()
{
               
   var a = document.getElementById('stock').value;
   var d = document.getElementById('edit1').value;
   var f=parseFloat(d)
   var e=parseFloat(a)
      if(f>=e)
      {
         alert("Matched");
         return true; 
      }
      else
      {
         alert("'Variation : '"+c)
         return false;
      }
               
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Item Code</th>
    <th>Item Description</th>
   <th>Quantity in Stock</th>
    <th>Batch Quantity</th>
    <th>Added Quantity</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='item001'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='itemdesc001'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='stock[]' id='stock' value='-25'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='edit[]' id='edit' value='24'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='edit1[]' id='edit1' value='24'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='item002'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='itemdesc002'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='stock[]' id='stock' value='24'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='edit[]' id='edit' value='24'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='edit1[]' id='edit1' value='24'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='item003'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='itemdesc003'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='stock[]' id='stock' value='165'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='edit[]' id='edit' value='4'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='edit1[]' id='edit1' value='10'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am fetching values from database and displaying it in table format using php.

I want to validate two fields those are quantity in stock and added stock where quantity in stock should be more than or equal to the added quantity.

I am  facing a problem with validating those dynamic fields.

i need to validate the text boxes whose ids are stock[] and edit

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You are asking a JavaScript question. Why post PHP and no JavaScript?

Comment: for validation i am using JavaScript for those two fields but am able to validate only for the first items and unable to validate the remaining fields. if you know how to validate please share the code with me

Comment: hai  mplungjan i made the changes that u asked please go through it

Comment: Please see the update I made to your snippet. That is the way we need it PLUS where do you call the checkmatch??? Can you post relevant RENDERED HTML ?

Comment: what part isnt working? do you have any errors? what are you expecting to happen that isnt (or visa versa)

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. If you create that exact table row you have shown us multiple times in a loop, you are violating that. Either modify the IDs dynamically while creating new rows - or find ways to navigate the DOM without clinging to IDs in the first place.

Comment: hai atmd, the thing is i am fetching the data from database and i need to compare the "quantity in stock" and "added stock" where the quantity in stock has to greater than or equal to added stock. my error is i can compare only the first field in table now i need to compare all the fields that are displaying in table.

Comment: @sai We UNDERSTAND that. What we do NOT understand is the HTML. Please post HTML with at LEAST 3 rows. You likely need to change the code to loop over `document.querySelectorAll(".edit")` after changing the id=edit to class=edit - same for edit1 and stock

Comment: @mplungjan sir please check it now for once

Comment: @sai Much better. So where do you call this. And what are your plans to loop? And can the user change the quantities?

Comment: it is used in production department and based on the product the items and the stock values will change according to product preparation. now based on quantity in stock and added stock values the form has to submit other wise error mess has to display.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the IDs to class
2. Loop over the fields on submit and stop submission if there is an error
3. Add event handlers to handle any input in the field that you want the user to update

```js
function checkmatch(fld) {
  var row = fld.closest("tr")
  var stock = +row.querySelector(".stock").value;
  var added = +row.querySelector(".edit1").value;
  row.querySelector(".res").innerHTML = added <= stock ? ' Matched': '<b class="vari">Variation: ' + Math.abs(stock - added)+'</b>';
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("table1").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var obj = e.target;
    if (obj.classList.contains("edit1")) checkmatch(obj)
  })
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".edit1").forEach(function(fld) {checkmatch(fld)})
    var variation = document.getElementById("table1").querySelector(".vari")
    if (variation) {
      e.preventDefault()
      alert("Please fix the variation in " + variation.closest("tr").querySelector("td").firstElementChild.value);
      var inp = variation.closest("td").querySelector("input")
      inp.select();
      inp.focus();
    }  
  })
  // when loading
  document.querySelectorAll(".edit1").forEach(function(fld) {checkmatch(fld)})
  
})
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <th>Item Code</th>
      <th>Item Description</th>
      <th>Quantity in Stock</th>
      <th>Batch Quantity</th>
      <th>Added Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='item001'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='itemdesc001'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='stock[]' class='stock' value='-25'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='edit[]' class='edit' value='24'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='edit1[]' class='edit1' value='24'><span class="res"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='item002'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='itemdesc002'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='stock[]' class='stock' value='24'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='edit[]' class='edit' value='24'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='edit1[]' class='edit1' value='24'><span class="res"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='item003'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='iname[]' value='itemdesc003'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='stock[]' class='stock' value='165'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='edit[]' class='edit' value='4'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='edit1[]' class='edit1' value='10'><span class="res"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: No bro its not working, and the form is submitting with out validating fields

Comment: do i have to add any scripting files with this code and this is error  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at "

Comment: See update. You will have to add IDs to table and form and add a span to the cell or a cell to the table with class="res"

Comment: As you can see it is working here. So your HTML is different. Look in the consome "It is not working" is not helpful for me to help you. Did you add the pan or cells with class res?